# MySQL - merge messages and replies by user

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL database

**messages**

```
email           message_id   content   time_sent
test@test.ee    1            aaa       2012-11-01 01:09:47
test@test.ee    2            ddd       2012-11-01 01:18:47
```

**replies**

```
message_id   content  time_sent
1            bbb      2012-11-01 01:12:47
1            ccc      2012-11-01 01:14:47
2            eee      2012-11-01 01:19:47
```

I need to get all messages by certain email merged with replies ordered by time_sent.
This would be perfect:

```
email          content  time_sent
test@test.ee   aaa      2012-11-01 01:09:47
               bbb      2012-11-01 01:12:47
               ccc      2012-11-01 01:14:47
test@test.ee   ddd      2012-11-01 01:18:47
               eee      2012-11-01 01:19:47
```

Even a tip where to start from would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `select m.content, r.content, m.message_id, m.email from messages m, replies r where m.message_id = r.message_id;`  

Gives me only messages which have a reply.
I tried joining, which probably isn't the solution for this query.
Should I create two select statement, and somehow use union to merge these? I'm not really familiar with MySQL, so it would be helpful to get a tip where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT email, content, time_sent
  FROM messages
 UNION ALL
SELECT m.email, r.content, r.time_sent
  FROM replies r JOIN messages m
    ON r.message_id = m.message_id
 ORDER BY email, time_sent
```

Output:

```
|        EMAIL | CONTENT |                       TIME_SENT |
|--------------|---------|---------------------------------|
| test@test.ee |     aaa | November, 01 2012 01:09:47+0000 |
| test@test.ee |     bbb | November, 01 2012 01:12:47+0000 |
| test@test.ee |     ccc | November, 01 2012 01:14:47+0000 |
| test@test.ee |     ddd | November, 01 2012 01:18:47+0000 |
| test@test.ee |     eee | November, 01 2012 01:19:47+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0af96/2)** demo

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
It's almost what I need, but I should get it working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select email as email,content,time_sent
FROM 
message
UNION
Select '' as email, content,time_sent
FROM
replies
```